# GetNewClosure and Start-Job

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm having trouble understanding how GetNewClosure works in conjunction with Start-Job. Case in point I have the following code

```
function Test([string]$Name)
{
     $block = { Write-Host "Name = $Name" }.GetNewClosure()
     &$block
     Other $block
     OtherJob $block
}

function Other([scriptblock]$Block)
{
    Write-Host -NoNewline "In Other: "
    &$Block
}

function OtherJob([scriptblock]$Block)
{
    Write-Host -NoNewline "In OtherJob: "
    $j = Start-Job -ScriptBLock $Block
    Start-Sleep -s 1
    $j | Receive-Job
}
```

When calling the code I get

```
PS C:\> Test "foo"
Name = foo
In Other: Name = foo
In OtherJob: Name =
```

Notice that $Name is not captured in OtherJob.

It is probably related to Start-Job starting a new PS instance, but is there any workaround for this (Preferably one that does not include using -ArgumentList)?

PS: The version table should it matter

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                                                    
----                           -----                                                                                    
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5485                                                                           
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514                                                                           
PSVersion                      2.0                                                                                      
WSManStackVersion              2.0                                                                                      
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}                                                                               
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                  
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more googling yielded a potential workaround taken from

[Powershell - how to pre-evaluate variables in a scriptblock for Start-Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834643/powershell-how-to-pre-evaluate-variables-in-a-scriptblock-for-start-job)

Basically you can use

```
$otherBlock = [scriptblock]::Create("Write-Host 'Name = $Name'")
OtherJob $otherBlock
```

Or set the variables in -InitializationScript